# Apache Server protocols

Tags: apache, module, protocols

Can the Apache Server be configured to use other protocols and not just HTTP/HTTPS ?

I think this should be possible by using modules.

Any answer is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache is able to support other protocols if someone were to write the appropriate support module.  A good example is [mod_ftp](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_ftp/mod/mod_ftp.html), which turns Apache into an FTP server.